# Flask-login and LDAP authentification

Tags: python, flask, ldap

i cant't connect to the following LDAP Test Server. Every input or suggestions are appreciated.

LDAP Server Information

```
Server: ldap.forumsys.com  
Port: 389

Bind DN: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
Bind Password: password
```

All user passwords are `password`.

```
individual Users (uid) and Group (ou) 

ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com
riemann
gauss
euler
euclid
```

**Flask**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    l = ldap.open("ldap.forumsys.com", port=389)
    username = "uid=einstein,ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com"
    password = "password"
    try:
      l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
      l.simple_bind_s(username, password)
      return "hi"

    except Exception, error:
      return "no"
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing all possible errors? Remove the try/except entirely and see why it fails.

Comment: this is the error message:INVALID_CREDENTIALS: {'desc': 'Invalid credentials'}
but
username: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
password: password
is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue, I fixed by following below:

use 
l.simple_bind(username, password)
instead of 
l.simple_bind_s(username, password)